# Amplify signIn works but currentAuthenticatedUser doesn't

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make a react native app using AWS as the backend. I have made a functional "appStack" that I wan't the user to be able to use after they have signed in/up. If they are not signed in then they are directed to my "loginStack" of the app.

When the user tries to login (with correct details) I get a console.log returning "success" as expected from the following code:

```
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

async function signIn(username, password) {
  try {
    const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
    console.log("success");
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error signing in", error);
  }
}

export default signIn;
```

But despite receiving this success message I don't get redirected to the AppStack as I expect to happen from app.js (see below), instead the Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() still returns null.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Amplify, Auth, Hub } from "aws-amplify";
import awsExports from "./src/aws-exports";

import AppNavigator from "./AppNavigator";
import LoginNavigator from "./LoginNavigator";

Amplify.configure(awsExports);



export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);

  const checkUser = async () => {
    const authUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true });
    setUser(authUser);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    checkUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user ? <AppNavigator /> : <LoginNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance.